# Python: How to dynamically assign variable in tkinter's checkbutton

Tags: python, oop, tkinter, object-oriented-analysis

I am trying to generate a few check buttons based on a list.
I have created an iteration and try to generate the check buttons. I struggle however with assigning 'variable' option. I have tried to use `'self.bttn%d' % i` to assign variable option to each of the buttons, but every time I try to get the value via the `self.bttn0.get()` method it returns `None`.

Could you explain me please how to solve the problem?

```python
def create_widgets(self):
    #Create whole menu
    my_menu = [("Dish 1", 24.99),
               ("Dish 2", 19.99),
               ("Dish 3", 14.99),
               ("Dish 4", 7.99)]
    menu_pos = len(my_menu)
    self.bttnx = my_menu[0][1]


    # ----- LABEL 'Title' -----
    Label(self,
          text = "Make an order by choosing one or more dishes from our menu."
          ).grid(row = 0, column = 0, sticky = W)

    # ----- BUTTONS -----
    for i in range(menu_pos):
        exec('self.bttn' + str(i) + ' = ' + 'BooleanVar()')
        #Check-buttons
        Checkbutton(self,
                    text = my_menu[i][0] + " / " + str(my_menu[i][1]) + "nok",
                    variable = 'self.bttn%d' % i
                    ).grid(row = i + 1, column = 0, sticky = W)

    Button(self,
           text = "Update",
           command = self.update_menu
           ).grid(row = 5, column = 0, sticky = W)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create your variables in a sequence, and address them at button creation.

Something like this:

```
bool_vars = [BooleanVar() for _ in range(menu_pos)]
for idx, var in enumerate(bool_vars):
    Checkbutton(self,
                text=my_menu[idx][0] + " / " + str(my_menu[idx][1]) + "nok",
                variable=var
                ).grid(row=idx+1, column=0, sticky=W)
```

Comment: Hi! Thanks a lot for your feedback. As BooleanVar() just returns value of True or False, it does not help me much in this case. By calling 'self.update_menu' method I need to know which buttons have changed its variable.

Comment: Sorry, you're totally right. Everything works fine right now. It was my fault.